# Objective C : linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker-errors, duplicate-symbol

This is the error I'm getting when I try to build my app.

> ld: 10 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64

[image]

Comment: The actual error is "Duplicate Symbol". You are including one or more classes more than once in your project.

Answer (score 0):

From the error, I would guess that:

- you have two files, `VaultSelectionViewController.m` and `SetLockViewController.m` (the first being originally a copy of the second, probably)
- they both contain `@implementation SetLockViewController`, and identical properties and/or methods and/or instance variables.

Solution: fix the class name in the `@implementation` to match the file name.

If that's not the issue, please provide the relevant parts of both files.

Answer (score 0):

Your project twice referring to file `SetLockViewController.m`.
My suggestion is take a copy of class out side of your project.

[1] Then right click on `SetLockViewController.m` file and delete  > move to trash.

[2] Go to project files directory in finder. Then delete the file `SetLockViewController.m` (if you find any).

[3] Clean the build and run.

Follow same method if any other duplicate files/linker errors present.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. Make sure your compile sources does not have dup files. (Bad merge can cause this issue.) Remove them and add them again can fix this build error.
2. Make sure you does not implement one function twice. (Copy codes and forget to rename the @implement XXX? Or copy and paste one function twice?) Just search the function define in your project and remove the dup one.

Answer (score 0):

Please check all the variables name in every classes of your project and make sure that all they have unique name including outside the class